# how to remove files from a windows machine without wiping the drive?

Tags: file-management

I would like to make it reasonably difficult to recover files from a windows 8 machine without wiping the drive. I have tried the usual file delete techniques from the specified directories and the recycle bin. Not sure what is next. i.e. is there a tool for this?

Comment: Yes, there are tools. We're not telling what the are ;)

Comment: Np. Just found them.